# Is it possible to get a Racing time of 2:23 legitimately?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I saw from the World Record of some racing events: `00:02.23`! What? Is such a thing possible?

How can people achieve this? What strategy do people use to get such low times?

Comment: It's very possible that the person who got that time, found some bug. I think it's to early for hacks/cheats since there is constant updates of the game making the hacks out of date quickly.

Comment: Reminds me of *Batman Arkham Asylum*, where the top players all have a time record of `00:00.00` and a combat highscore of `9'999'999` which is obviously impossible without somehow cheating.

Comment: They probably either found a glitch or cheated.  Even on races with really short laps in a super car 2 seconds isn't nearly enough time.  It's also possible the leaderboards are bugged.  I got the award for getting a world record in a race somehow but I seriously doubt my driving skills are good enough for that.

Answer (score 2):

No. I believe the shortest race is Criminal Records (circular track around the prison), which takes about 30 seconds per lap.

I think a time of 2.23 seconds is impossible using legitimate means, such as cutting corners and/or slipstreaming. It is more likely to be a leaderboard error or the result of cheating or a glitch.

Answer (score 0):

When the online portion first started, many glitched world records appeared - my current best time for arm wrestling is 0:00:00. If you look through a lot of the leaderboards, there are plenty of times for different activities that simply aren't possible.